# How can i restrict the WIFI access for a specific IP

Tags: android

I want to create application that restricts the internet access from WIFI from a specific IP (or address).

Is is possible to create Android application for that?

Comment: Hopefully not without a rooted device.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot tell the android wifi service to block the internet.

What you can do is, make an service that checks the IP adress when WiFi is enabled, and when it is that specific IP addres, disable the WiFi.

```
wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i think i wasn't clear on the question. what u meant is that i want to restrict the user from getting into sites with specific IP address and not the actual WIFI ip address.